# Как вывести GIF-Изображение по нажатию button

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю развивающую игру для ребенка.Нужно что бы при нажатии на обычную кнопку которая находится на форме,
появлялась картинка в виде GIF анимации и задерживалась на экране секунд на 5 примерно. Пробовал делать через PictureBox но там вместо анимации просто картинка без движения. И она появляется вместо кнопки, а надо что бы она появлялась отдельно и исчезала.

Comment: _Пробовал делать_ - не верю! (c). Покажите ваш код. / WinForms? Добавьте метку.

Comment: В коде почти нечего нет, один button и воспроизведение звука. по нажатию. Да WinForms

Comment: А как вы вставляете так, что у вас PictureBox элемент перекрывает Button? PictureBox поддерживает анимированные GIF картинки. Вставлять например так: `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Images/animated.gif");`. Отображением управляйте свойством `Visible` через таймер. По умолчанию картинка скрыта. Когда нужно показываете и включаете таймер по истечению которого скрываете картинку.

Comment: Я кидаю на форму PictureBox, потом в его свойствах загружаю GIF, и меняю размер. Если его наложить поверх кнопки, то при нажатии он ее перекроет этой самой картинкой.

Comment: Можно как-то отделить PictureBox от самой формы?